# Display 2 level of json key value pairs in a table with top and side header in Angular project

Tags: json, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have the following key value pairs in a table. The table is needed in Angular platform, so *ngFor loop would be something that would be used. I am looking for an efficient way where it there is no workaround such as creating 2 table and joining them.

```
{"Lawrence":{"Unallocated":215,"All":2,"Both":0,"Slabs":3,"Tiles":121},"West":{"Unallocated":82,"All":1,"Both":0,"Slabs":1,"Tiles":1},"King":{"Unallocated":388,"All":15,"Both":12,"Slabs":264,"Tiles":558}}
```

I am looking to have a table as such

|  | Unallocated | All | Both | Slabs | Tiles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lawrence | 215 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 121 |
| West | 82 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| King | 388 | 15 | 12 | 264 | 558 |

I have tried various ways from bootstrap but have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data=JSON.parse(`{"Lawrence":{"Unallocated":215,"All":2,"Both":0,"Slabs":3,"Tiles":121},"West":{"Unallocated":82,"All":1,"Both":0,"Slabs":1,"Tiles":1},"King":{"Unallocated":388,"All":15,"Both":12,"Slabs":264,"Tiles":558}}`)

const newData=Object.entries(data).map(([key,value])=>{
  const y={['title']:key}
  return Object.assign({},y,value)
})

const headers=Object.keys(newData[0])
console.log(headers)

console.log(JSON.stringify(newData,null,4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks.. i have implemented with some change. Even though this was not exactly what i was looking for. I have up voted it as it has been helpful.